# Ctrlp custom ignore regular expression

Tags: regex, vim, ctrlp

Documentation of `Ctrlp` has example of ignoring folders:

`let g:ctrlp_custom_ignore = '\v[\/]\.(git|hg|svn)$'`.

And the one that is currently used locally and works (default config files from [dotfiles](https://github.com/skwp/dotfiles)):

`let g:ctrlp_custom_ignore = '\.git$\|\.hg$\|\.svn$'`

I've got folders `_build`, `node_modules` etc. that should be ignored, but having added new folders to the list did not solve my problems and all files still appear in the list of files, that makes `Ctrlp` almost useless.

My expression looked like this:

`let g:ctrlp_custom_ignore = '\.git$\|\.hg$\|\.svn$\|_build$'`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Remove `$` after `_build`. It can prevent matching the folders.